# If Statement in Google App Script to Match Date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a simple if statement in Google App Script for Sheets and having a bit of trouble equating a formula with a date.

Here is my code right now.

```
function addNewRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tab1");  
  var rng = sh.getRange("A1");
  var date = sh.getRange("B1");

  if (rng > date) {
     sh.getRange("J10").copyTo(sh.getRange(2, 2), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to have the if statement check if the date in A1 is greater than B1. If it is, then return the value, else nothing.

It looks like the formula I'm using in A1 is `I8-MOD(WEEKDAY(I8),7)` and in B1 is 1/1/2014 so I the issue is likely converting `I8-MOD(WEEKDAY(I8),7)` to the date somehow, however I'm not sure how best to fix this. Is there a App Script formula that would do this? Or should we I set up another variable to save the data with and use that in the if statement.

Thanks in advance!
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write

```
  var rng = sh.getRange("A1");
  var date = sh.getRange("B1");
```

you are getting ranges, not values...

so please change that to

```
  var rng = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var date = sh.getRange("B1").getValue();
```

and it should go better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially still comparing a range here.

Instead, the following will compare the contents in the way you desire:

```
if (rng.getValue() > date.getValue()) {
```

If you check the logger, you will see that your if statement above produces "Range" for both values.